# to find combination of target value equal to 0 , VBA

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I need to find the combination of values  which will have the total sum equal to zero in Excel. Solver is possible to provide the solution for non zero values. However, it is not working if the target value = 0. Could you please help me in this. What i have done: I tried solver but it is incorrect if we use target sum =0.  I have used similar codes available in the net. But getting same no results.

[image: Example details in the image]

Comment: Please provide a create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and tell us what youve done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solver will not provide solution if the target sum is 0.

My solution is:

1) find the sum of values.

2) use the sum as the target value.

3) Now solver will give solution for the Target value.

4) if you segregate the remaining values, you will get the combination of values , whose sum is 0

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Target As Double, OpTarget As Double
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastRow

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            Target = .Range("A" & i).Value
            OpTarget = "-" & Target

            .Range("B" & i).Value = OpTarget
            .Range("C" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("A" & i & ":B" & i))
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]